# WPF usercontrol - write DependencyProperty value back to XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have a usercontrol which contains a label and a textbox. Label and textbox are placed side by side. I have a DependencyProperty called LabelWidth that is bound to the labels width for adjusting the labels width.

Now, when I'm sizing the control using the VisualStudio Designer, I want the control to scale differently when Crtl is pressed. Some code:

```
void Control_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    bool labelResizeMode = Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl);
    if (labelResizeMode)
    {
        if (e.PreviousSize.Width > 0 && e.PreviousSize.Height > 0)
        {
            double diff = e.NewSize.Width - e.PreviousSize.Width;
            this.LabelWidth += diff;
        }
    }
}

public double LabelWidth
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(LabelWidthProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LabelWidthProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LabelWidth", typeof(double), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(100.0));
```

The problem is that the value for LabelWidth is not written back to the xaml code when the control is resized. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by *the value for LabelWidth is not written back to the xaml code*?

Comment: The control is defined in a view like this:


`<myNS:MyUserControl LabelText="This is the label text" LabelWidth="80" Margin="163,239,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222"/>`

So when I change the size for that control in the designer while Ctrl is pressed, the value for LabelWidth get's updated, but the new value isn't reflected to the XAML-code.

Comment: If you write `LabelWidth="80"` in your XAML, there is no code that you can write that will update that value as the program runs... it doesn't work that way. What are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, I know that. I don't want the LabelWidth="80" to be updated when the program runs. I want it to be updated when I change the size of the control in the designer at design time.

Comment: That won't happen either because the `Control_SizeChanged` will only be called when the program is running.

Comment: No, Control_SizeChanged is called when the control is resized at design time.

Comment: Huh... well they say that we learn something new every day... I did not know that. Even so, the text in the XAML file will never be changed like this. Just the current value of the `DependencyProperty` will be updated.